Credit/overdraft limit on bank accounts in Lithuania
In some EU states (such as Austria, Germany and Italy), it is quite common to have an overdraft limit on one’s bank account, allowing for a negative balance, usually until the next monthly salary arrives.
Here in Lithuania, I have been unable to find much information about such an option (banking terms seem to be “sąskaitos kreditavimas”, “kredito linija” or “kredito limitas”).
My German bank has an option in their online banking portal to request, change or revoke a credit line, but I am unable to find a similar item in the portal of my Lithuanian bank. An online search found descriptions of such services with a number of banks, but all of them were for business accounts, not for consumer accounts. There was one exception – Swedbank, who offered a credit line on consumer bank accounts but stopped approving new credit lines or raising existing ones in July 2023.
Banks do offer credit cards with a certain credit line, but as I understand it, the credit line only applies to payments or cash withdrawals made with the card, not for e.g. money transfers or “elektroninė sąskaita” (electronic invoice, a form of direct debit).
So what is the common way of getting an on-demand credit (when needed, as much as needed up to a previously agreed limit, at previously agreed conditions, with no need to explicitly request it each time) in Lithuania?
